Reference for theorem about stability of fixed points of iterated k-linear maps
Consider the following iterated map
$$ x^{i+1} = f(x^i) $$
where $x \in \mathbb{C}^N$, and where the function $f: \mathbb{C}^N \to \mathbb{C}^N$ can be written as a $k$-linear function with $x$ as each of the $k$ arguments $ f(x) = F(x,x,\dots,x)$. I'm interested in the stability of fixed points $x^*$ of this map. I believe it is true that for any $k \geq 1$, non-zero fixed points $x^* \neq 0 $ are unstable because the Jacobian around them possesses an eigenvalue of $k$, and for any $k > 1$, the fixed point at the origin is stable.
I have a couple of questions:

Can someone point me to a reference/name for this fact? I've done a fair amount of looking online, but I think I just have the wrong search terms.

Are there more general results for when this will be true? For example, if $f$ is a sum of a linear and quadratic function, can you say anything about its stability based on these functions?

(or 0, I guess) Am I totally wrong about this? See the proof below.


Consider the dynamics near a non-zero fixed point $x^* \neq 0$ (which satisfies $x^* = f(x^*)$). Writing $x^i = x^* + \epsilon y^i$, we look for the  dynamics of $y$ by plugging this in to the iterated map
$$ x^* + \epsilon y^{i+1} = F(x^* + \epsilon y^i,x^* + \epsilon y^i,\dots, x^* + \epsilon y^i) $$
If $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, i.e., we are sufficiently close to the fixed point, we can drop everything beyond $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$. Doing this, we have
$$ x^* + \epsilon y^{i+1} = F(x^*,x^*, \dots, x^*) + \epsilon\bigg( F(y,^i,x^*,\dots,x^*) + F(x^*,y^i,\dots,x^*) + \dots + F(x^*,x^*,\dots,y^i) \bigg)$$
So, the dynamics of $y$ are given by the linear map
$$y^{i+1} = L_{x^*}(y^i) \equiv F(y^i,x^*,\dots,x^*) + F(x^*,y^i,\dots,x^*) + \dots + F(x^*,x^*,\dots,y^i) $$
If the operator $L_{x^*}$ has eigenvalues within the unit circle, we say the $x^*$ is a stable fixed point; otherwise we say it's unstable. This is all very standard so far. The key part is  $L_{x^*}$ has an eigenvalue of $k$ associated with the eigenvector $x^*$. This can be seen by plugging $x^*$ in to $L_{x^*}$,
$$
 L_{x^*}(x^*) = F(x^*,x^*,\dots,x^*) + F(x^*,x^*,\dots,x^*) + \dots + F(x^*,x^*,\dots,x^*)
$$
But each term on the right is $x^*$, so we have $L_{x^*}(x^*) = kx^*$, so there is an eigenvalue of $k$.
That the fixed point at the origin is stable if $k > 1$ is easy to see --- $L_{x^*}$ always outputs zero in this case.
A correlary, I think, is that there are also no (nonzero) stable $n$-point periodic orbits. Points on these orbits $x^{n*}$ must satisfy $x^{n*} = f(f(\dots f(x^{n*}) \dots ) ) $, and have the same criterion for stability. But, this can be written as a $k^n$-linear map, and there are (nonzero) stable fixed points.
Cheers
